# Implementing Sign in using Twitter, Omniauth and Devise

Tags: twitter, devise, omniauth

I am referring to these railscasts for implementing signing in using twitter, omniauth and devise:

1. http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1?view=asciicast
2. http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2?view=asciicast

**Scenario:** A twitter user comes to my app. Clicks on the Twitter link to sign in and is taken to /auth/twitter. He allows my app on the twitter site and is redirected back to my app. He enters his email id on my site as that is mandatory. He uses the site and then signs out of my app. He then wants to log back in again. He clicks on the Twitter sign in icon again.
**My problem:** I expected that he would not have to authorize my app once again on the twitter site. But, that is not the case. This time again, twitter asks this user to authorize.

My code follows the railscasts exactly:

```
 <routes.rb>
 match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'


class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
...
def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]

    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])

    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end
...
end
```

User model from Devise is modified as:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :authentications

    def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
        authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
    end

    def password_required?
        (authentications.empty? || !password.blank?) && super
    end
end
```

What do I need to do to ensure that a returning user is not asked to authorize my app everytime s/he is redirected to /auth/twitter ???

Comment: And my omniauth initializer looks like: 'Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter,
  ***********************,
  ***********************
end'

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it with this answer:

[Rails omniauth - twitter asking for app authorization each time user logs in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251519/rails-omniauth-twitter-asking-for-app-authorization-each-time-user-logs-in/8262479#8262479)

You have to add the client_options hash.

Answer (score 0):

if you follow the ryan bates casts about devise and omniauth your user model should have an associations between the user and the authentication.

User model need something like this:
has_many :authentications

Your routes.rb file needs also the ressource:

match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create'

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations'}

resources :authentications

Hope this will help.

Best regards
Jan